# How to setup github actions to run headful puppeteer for E2E extension testing

Tags: github, continuous-integration, puppeteer, build-automation, github-actions

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have a requirement to not allow my github users to merge to master if tests fail. The merge button in github should be disabled and test details should be shown.

I decided to implement these requirement using github actions.

My problem is:
How to setup github actions workflow, to install XVFB to run HEADFUL E2E tests using puppeteer for testing extensions?

I would be running tests on windows(xvfb?), mac, ubuntu.

Also is it possible to run tests on my Digital Ocean server instead of github's container? I have everything setup here and it works!

Lastly, I cannot replace
1. puppeteer
2. Node
3. Github actions
with some other library/tool.

Comment: I think you can now use https://github.com/marketplace/actions/gabrielbb-xvfb-action

Answer (score -1):

You can run tests on your own server but to do so you'll probably have to create the link between the two (e.g. GHA calls your server and then displays its output).

At the moment it's probably easier to use an action with Puppeteer (like [Puppeteer Headful](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/puppeteer-headful)) or create a docker image with the necessary tools.

```
# This is an example configuration, you'll still need to create your own DockerFile
on: push
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: your-image-with-puppeteer-and-xvfb
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm test
```